# html jquery function don't work but replaceWith does

Tags: jquery, html, replacewith

I have realy strange behavior. I have this code (I remove unrelated code).

```
$(function() {
        function get_translations() {
            $('#translations tr').not(':eq(0)').remove();
            var item = {
                context: "1: context",
                term: "2: term",
                translation: "3: translation"
            };  

            var tr = $('<tr/>').
                append('<td class="context">' + (item.context || '&nbsp;') + '</td>').
                append('<td class="original-string">' + item.term + '</td>').
                append('<td class="translation translated-string">' + item.translation +
                       '</td>').
                append('<td class="delete-col"><button class="'+
                       'delete translation-delete">X</button></td>').
                data('term', item.term || '').
                data('translation', item.translation || '').
                data('context', item.context || '').
                appendTo('#translations');
        }
        get_translations();

       $('td.translation').live('click', function() {
           var $this = $(this);
           if ($this.find('textarea').length == 0) {
               var text = $this.empty().parent().data('translation');
               //$this.data('content', text).empty();
               $this.html('<tex' + 'tarea>' + text + '</text' +
                 'area><button>Save</button><a href="#" class="_cancel">Cancel</a>');
               //appendTo($this);
           }
       });
       $('td.translation button').live('click', function() {
           var td = $(this).parent();
           var tr = td.parent();
           console.log(td);
           td.html('foo');
           //td.replaceWith('<td class="translation translated-string">foo</td>');
       });
});
```

in `$('td.translation button')` handler `td.html('foo');` don't work but `td.replaceWith('<td class="translation translated-string">foo</td>');` does. No errors, it simply do nothing.

I try to recreate this behavior using this:

```
$(function() {
    $('table').append('<tr><td>:empty</td></tr>');
    $('td').live('click', function() {
        var tr = $(this).parent();
        $(this).html('<textarea></textarea><a class="foo" href="#">a:</a>');
    });
    $('.foo').live('click', function() {
        var td = $(this).parent();
        var tr = td.parent();
        td.html(':empty');
        return false;
    });
});
```

but above code work.

I can use `replaceWith`, but I what to know why `html` function doesn't work. Anybody know why?

**UPDATE**: When I add this `window.td = td;` I can call html from console and it work.

Comment: Be more specific than "doesn't work" - does nothing happen, do you get a Javascript error, do you get an unexpected result?

Comment: What is the expected result? `.html('foo')` will not create a DOM element with the foo class of course...

Comment: @AnthonyGrist @gdoron It should do `<td>foo</td>` but it don't, nothing happen, when I do `td.replaceWith('<td>foo</td>');` then it change td to foo. In my working code it's inline edit.

Comment: @jcubic And no Javascript errors in your console?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist no errors, and only that one line `td.html('foo');` don't give any results.

Comment: Very odd. I think we may need to see a jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Side note; I would strongly recommend constructing a `string` of HTML before, and then `append`ing it all in one go, from a performance head this is much more preferred. :)

Comment: here's jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3AB8Q/1/

Comment: @Richard In my code I use `visibility: hidden` so browser didn't do reflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using hint from @Tats_innit I put `alert('call')` to `$('td.translation').live('click'` and it was executed when I click the button. First it execute button handler (it change html and alert message box) and then invoke handler for td and create textarea again.

Comment: Also if I may recommend `:)` please use `.on` instead of `.live` it is deprecated in latest version. So I hope this is resolved now, right? i.e. I will stop reading  your code. `:P`

Comment: Yay, happy `:)` times, also please use `.on`

Answer (score 1):

See demo here and watch the alert with http://jsfiddle.net/QknuZ/2/ (with `td.html()`)

I hope this answers your question: HTML `html()` will replaces the contents of the element, while replaceWith() replaces the actual element.

http://api.jquery.com/html/

http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

The `replaceWith` removes the element from DOM, and then adds the html back again.

Please please correct me if I am wrong, hope this helps.

**Image**

[image]

Comment: Great, but why this work then http://jsfiddle.net/27c2V/ (it's the code in the question where I want to replicate this behavior).

Comment: @jcubic cooleos, I am 89 % sure its to do with the way dynamic html is getting appended i.e. compare the text area of the jsfiddle with the main code you got above. Let me read the code in your new fiddle `:)`

Comment: Thanks for you hint, I add my own answer, event handler for td was executed (because of the event bubbling) after button handler. Probably replaceWith remove this event with the DOM element.

Comment: @jcubic Glad it helped, yes `replaceWith` defo (100%) `removes the content from DOM` http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/ `:)` also see my comment below in your post